# What is TK's actual name?

Tags: angel-beats

"TK" is a mysterious character who tends to speaks in nonsensical English phrases depending on the situation.

Was it ever revealed what is his actual name? Also, why do the other SSS members call him "TK"?

[image: TK!!]

Comment: Just a side note: His nonsensical English phrases are actually mostly lines from songs. :)

Comment: And another side note: tee kay (TK) means "OK" in Hindi. Cool, eh?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[What kuwaly said](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/3111/2516), his real identity is still unknown. But if you're willing to accept some guesses (some of which are taken from [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WMG/AngelBeats)) as to why he calls himself TK, his name could be derived from:

- [Tetsuya Komuro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetsuya_Komuro), the most successful producer in Japanese music history. His nickname is also TK and most of the [songs that TK references](https://angelbeats.fandom.com/wiki/TK#Phrases) come from TM Network which Tetsuya is the lead singer of.
- [Tachibana Kanade](https://angelbeats.fandom.com/wiki/Kanade_Tachibana), the team killer. Tachibana's [guard skills](https://angelbeats.fandom.com/wiki/Kanade_Tachibana#List_of_Guard_Skills) are named after common effects of [effects pedals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effects_unit).
- [To come](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_come_(publishing)), which is used to signify that additional material will be added at a later date.
- Time keeper. Inspired by [What are the positions "CA", "TK", and "AP"?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/28838/8486).
- A shorthand for とにかくキてる (Tonikaku Kiteru, "an eccentric person anyhow"), a nickname given by Noda in chapter 40 of the [*Angel Beats! Heaven's Door*](https://angelbeats.fandom.com/wiki/Heaven%27s_Door) manga. This might be the canonical answer as to what TK signifies and how he received that name; the manga's plot after Shiina's recruitment to the SSS seems to be based on Jun Maeda's new writings, according to [Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel_Beats!#cite_ref-96).

  [image: TK's name, Angel Beats! Heaven's Door chapter 40, page 21]
- Tainted kerchief. This nameless guy who died in the train accident in episode 9 also wore a "red" bandana like TK's.

  [image: Is this guy TK?]

Answer (score 5):

According to [this wiki](http://angelbeats.wikia.com/wiki/TK):

> His real identity and his name are still unknown even to the SSS, so they identify him as "TK", a nickname he gave himself.

Answer (score 1):

According to the manga *Angel Beats! Heaven's Door*, it was NODA who gave him that nickname since SSS always calls him 'that guy from whatever kingdom come' why not shorten it to TK instead?

Yurippe also thinks he's got [savant syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savant_syndrome) for he's incapable of having a conversation with them.