# What are the positions "CA", "TK", and "AP"?

Tags: anime-production, kowabon

The credits for each episode of *Kowabon* feature credits for the positions "CA", "TK", and "AP". For example, from episode 11:

[image]

What are these positions? The official website for *Kowabon* doesn't list these positions on [its staff page](https://www.kbc.co.jp/kowabon/staff/), and I don't believe I've seen them in the credits of any other anime I've watched. (With these being two-letter acronyms, I have no idea how to search for them effectively.)

I suspect that they might have something to do with *Kowabon* being rotoscoped (note: the topmost position in the screenshot above is "cameraman", which is something you're only likely to find when rotoscoping is involved). Though, then again, I had a look at the credits of an episode of *Aku no Hana*, and didn't see these particular positions credited (though they could've been there under some other name).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't know about kowabon, but In general.

CA: Camera assistant.
TK: Time keeper. (who check length of script that match to scene.)
AP: Assistant producer.

Evidence:
CA is positioned next to カメラマン"Camera Man".
TK is positioned next to 音声"Voice"
AP is positioned to last.

Comment: Great answer; that must be it (cf. http://tvman.jp/occupation/cameraassistant.html, http://tvman.jp/occupation/tk.html, http://tvman.jp/occupation/ap.html). That, at least, explains why I haven't seen "CA" and "TK" elsewhere (regular anime don't have a camera and don't actually shoot scenes); other anime have assistant producers, but they're usually just credited as アシスタントプロデューサー or something.